# How to make a function print nothing but "^@" with a | cat -e

Tags: c

I am recoding printf and the behavior I get from my printf is slightly different from the real printf one because I work with strings (which are malloc) and real printf works with write functions.

When doing :

> ./a.out | cat -e

of :

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf(%c, 0);
    return (0);
}
```

It is written ^@ in the terminal

Whereas my function react the same without the pipe (cat -e) but with the pipe still prints nothing. Can you tell me how I can get my function write the "^@" when a | cat -e is used on it?

Comment: Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is your question: *how do I implement the behaviour of `cat -e` within the C code using a function?*

Comment: with my printf function, when I do "./a.out | cat -e" with the same input (i.e %c and 0), it does not print the "^@". I want to make it print it when using the pipe | cat -e

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to say. Perhaps, you could update your question with input and expected output and whether you want to use `cat` or just simulate it in your C code itself.

Comment: @l3x I would like a C function that prints nothing in a terminal but ^@ when | cat -e is used

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? `printf(%c...` will not even compile. And `printf` and `cat` are meant to handle text, not binary data. Similar for the standard streams they use. If you have binary data, use a normal file or fifo and `fwrite`. To show whatever you want, convert yourself. `^@` is not even a single valid character.

Comment: "I would like a C function that prints nothing in a terminal but ^@ when | cat -e is used" - `printf("^@")`.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your function we could tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I *think* he's trying to send a `NUL` character to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the character ascii value `0`. It is a null value. When you are simply executing with `./a.out | cat` or `./a.out` it does not print anything. Because by default cat will not print non printable characters. But when you are using with `cat -e`, it is for printing the non-printable characters.

```
 printf("%c",0);
```

From the man page of `cat`,

```
 -e     equivalent to -vE
 -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line
 -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

Comment: How so maybe my question would be : how to print the non-printable char ^@

Comment: When I do the following command line one my printf function : ./a.out | cat -e, it does not print the ^@. I would like to print it without using write(1, "", 1) but with something I can malloc

Comment: @zakk8889 That's why they are called "non-printable": the characters have no corresponding glyph in the fonts, and often are simply removed/ignored when printed in terminals/etc. At best you would get displayed only a placeholder character for non-printable character. Some terminals support that feature - most not. Redirect the output to the file and open the file in hex editor, or redirect to hexdump/hd/od tools.

Comment: @Dummy00001: No glyph does not make a code a non-printable. Many fonts don't have glyphs for all character codes. non-printables are a cathegory of their own and used to control the terminal.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you guys. My question sounded stupid but I was useful for my understanding !

Comment: @Olaf, I have said "fonts" solely for the purpose of shortening the explanation.